# iOS: Safe & secure user response on a jailbroken phone?

Tags: ios, security, jailbreak, confirmation, enclave

What is the iOS way to provide a secure popup and store the user's agree/disagree response to some message in the secure enclave of the CPU chip? 
So even if you have a jailbroken phone, the user response is secure, only CPU and RAM are involved and the user response is securely stored?

Answer (score 1):

The screen contents and touch sensor are completely controlled by the application processor. Any attacker in control of those will be able to intercept and change anything displayed on the screen and received by the touch sensor. Note though that this is the case regardless of whether the device is jailbroken or not.

The only thing actually out of reach of the application processor input-wise would be TouchID/FaceID - you could ask for confirmation that way, but then you have the problem of handling it in your application. If your communication endpoints are SEP <--> your server, then you could have an RSA private key stored in SEP and have the server send a nonce that is to be signed. But if communication is SEP <--> your app, an attacker can just inject into your app and make it think it received what it wanted to see.

Comment: But SEP is just Apple's trustzone. I was under the impression that a trustlet running in an ARM trustzone does have access to some I/O. Maybe not on iOS?

Comment: TrustZone itself is just an architectural design that groups every processor/mode pair into either the "Secure World" or "Insecure World". You're likely thinking of EL3 but no, SEP does not run there, it's a different processor altogether. And while it certainly has _some_ MMIO, the screen is handled by the AP regardless.